# Can't upgrade to newest version of linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, boot, libc

So I got update as usual. Cant upgrade to newest version of linux-image. Initially , I found

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libavdevice58 ffmpeg libpostproc55 libavcodec58 libavutil56 libswscale5
  libswresample3 libavformat58 libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  coreutils gir1.2-mutter-10 libmutter-10-0 mutter-common snapd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic
cp: cannot stat '/lib/klibc-*.so': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc-utils failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cp: cannot stat '/lib/klibc-*.so': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc-utils failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So following the error I tried these following troubleshoot but it doesn't work :

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ended up with same error
2. tried finding klibc-utils `dpkg -l | grep klibc-utils` and got `ii  klibc-utils                                2.0.10-4                                amd64        small utilities built with klibc for early boot`
3. then so klib-.so files, I tried looking at content `dpkg -L klibc-utils` and found out there is no file with .so extension in my klib-utils. So i thought of reinstalling it but got the same error. then
   sudo apt-cache depends klibc-utils
   klibc-utils
   Depends: libklibc
   Breaks: initramfs-tools

```
dpkg -l | grep libklibc
ii  libklibc:amd64                             2.0.10-4                                amd64        minimal libc subset for use with initramfs
```

but seems I am moving anywhere. even booting with linux-image-6.5.0-26 giving me kernel panic and booting with older version going well. Tried live USB method but didn't work.

I am looking for serious help Otherwise I will move to all content from computer to cloud and then reinstall ubuntu 23.18 or whatever.
Thanks for even reading it. I am grateful.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.